# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, exception

I am getting this while trying to run build in debug mode

```html
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I already ran `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` before launching the app again. It still not going!
The `flutter doctor` command result is OK and fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally worked!
I solved the problem by adding adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` in the gradle.properties file and deleting the./gradle/cahes directly ✔️

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution by adding this line to gradle.properties.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Comment: Thanks Nikunj! It finally worked. But what does this line means?

Comment: To run Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It currently requires 2 or more GB of heap memory. so we are allocating 4GB of heap memory to grade